# Habilitar/Desabilitar botões angularjs com valores vindo da api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tenho minha seguinte tela : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O menu lateral, vem de uma Lista da api com as permissões do usuário

tenho minhas classes:

```
public class Menu {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
public class Item {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public Menu Menu {get;set;}
```

---

```
}
public class Opcao {
    public int {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public Item Item {get;set;}
}
```

Onde Menu = Cadastro

Item = Cliente

Opcao = Incluir, Editar,Excluir, Outros...

A listagem do menu lateral eu consegui perfeitamente, é só usar ng-repeat e pronto.

Meu problema é  a Opção, como vou jogar a correta para aquela view? para deixar habilitado / desabilitado os botões que ele tem ou não permissão?

Answer (score 1):

Como o AngularJS não trabalha com controle de acesso / permissão, eu usaria o ng-show/ng-hide dependendo de como vem sua estrutura de dados da API.

Um exemplo seria:

```
<tr>
   <td ng-show="user.hasPermitionToEdit">Editar</td>
   <td ng-show="user.hasPermitionToDelete">Excluir</td>
</tr>
```

Espero que tenha lhe ajudado.

Comment: pois é, isso sim, porém, como eu passo isso para a View? pois no menu por exemplo, é aonde ele vem as rotas...aí vem já com o nome...

Comment: Supondo que você tenha acesso ao o usuário (Item) na construção das Opções (Editar, etc.) e que o item da Opção seja o usuário que pode deletar, eu construiria uma função no controlador do tipo **isUserPermited(item, opcao.item)**, retornando um booleano caso o usuário da "sessão" seja o mesmo da opcao.item. Desta forma você poderia verificar o usuário nesta função, +/- como o exemplo abaixo:

`$scope.isUserPermited = function(userOnSession, userPermited) {
   // lógica que compara
};`

e sua view +/-:

`<td ng-show="isUserPermited(item, opcao.item)">Editar</td>`

Comment: fez sentido, vou tentar